# How to mock a class of a library used by the app during instrumented test?

Tags: android, mobile, automated-tests, android-uiautomator, mockk

I am working on an Android library and I am writing an instrumented test for it using UI Automator and Mockk.

The library has a class called *InstallManager* which will install stuff on the device. I want the *InstallManager* to throw an exception so that I can test if an error notification will be shown.

All I do is finding the Update (Install) button and click on it

```
        val updateButtonComponent = device.findObject(By.text(updateButtonText))
        updateButtonComponent.click()
```

**How can I mock/manipulate the *InstallManager* which is being used by the library during the automated test?**

---

**What I tried:**

I tried mocking the *InstallManager* before running the automated test, hoping that UI Automator would magically know that it should use this mocked InstallManager. But (as I thought already) it does not work like that...

```
private fun breakInstallManager() {
        installManager = spyk(InstallManager(mockk(relaxed = true), nonExistentFile))
        every { installManager.getString(any()) } returns ""
        every { installManager.packageName } returns ""
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For mocking InstallManager class in android tests, call `MockKAnnotations.init` method. Then in the test method you can specify the return value

```kotlin
    @RelaxedMockK
    private lateinit var installManager: InstallManager

    @Before
    fun setUp() {
        MockKAnnotations.init(this)
        // …
    }
    
    @Test
    fun installManagerTest(){
        every { installManager.getString(any()) } returns ""
        every { installManager.packageName } returns ""
        // …
    }
```